# Spring JPA Data scanning for repository does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

It seems like i have disable jpa repositories. Have this error:

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [C:\Users\jasiu\workspace2.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\BuyMyTime\WEB-INF\classes\web\UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [data.UserRepository] found for dependency [data.UserRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [data.UserRepository] found for dependency [data.UserRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"data"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"data"},
excludeFilters={
    @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, DataSource dataSource){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HelloWorld");
    dataSource.setUsername("login");
    dataSource.setPassword("haslo");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("data");
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    //properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    //adapter.setDatabase();
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    return adapter;
}

}
```

Repo is in package "data":

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByNick(String nick);
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
protected UserRepository userRepository;
...
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>BuyMyTime</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>BuyMyTime Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.ALPHA03</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>BuyMyTime</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please for any help.

Comment: `UserRepository` is in package `data` or `*.data.*` ?

Comment: Is it working if you're not that specific in `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: ByeBye - in package data, it works for components, but not for repository; Xtreme - if i clean specifics it does not make difference, same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is your project structure?  I copied your code on a project with UserRepository in basepackage.data and the repository was discovered.

I think it is because you have config and data children under default package.  I got it to work by moving your data, web and config packages under a common package.

Here are my configuration annotations

```
package basepackage.config;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"basepackage.data"})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=User.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"basepackage"})
public class MyConfig {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        repo.save(new User("u-"+i));
    }

}

}
```

You can also define your scanning by using basePackageClasses.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses={UserRepository.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=User.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"basepackage"})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does not work. If I remove properieties from scanning annotations it should scan all packages? But it didnt work too. I also not use spring boot, maybe i should start using it.

Comment: When I try to use AutoConfiguration with boot i have: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BuyMyTime]]

Comment: Even if I remove annotations Repository and Autowired under protected UserRepository i get error creating bean "userRepository" ? It's enough when i enableJpaRepositories and interface implements JpaRepository to scan this interface? This error is caused by NoSuchMethodError setTransactionManagerBeanName.

Comment: If you remove attribute, it doesn't scan all packages : Either basePackageClasses() or basePackages() (or its alias value()) may be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.  -- This is from the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

Comment: Scanning components works the same way with or without boot.  The difference is that spring-boot create a lot of default components depending on your configuration.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Scanning is working pretty well now, dont get any error but have another problem: "The requested resource is not available." for any request mapped, I will try to configure all environment again, cause i even not get any info about what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.
In my case the problem was at a @Configuration class that implemented Spring JPA Auditing.
I removed both @EnableTransactionManagement and @EnableJpaRepositories that were not necessary and the repositories were scanned again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed too and just added the below annotation to my main class.

@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.repository"})

Comment: This solution was already presented in the accepted answer.